# Selected rows using check box should be displayed inside the footer row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have requirement when we select the rows of the gridview using checkbox those selected rows should be displayed in the footer row of the grid
please let me know how we can do it using asp.net and c# programming.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4">
  <Columns> 
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username"> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>'></asp:Label> 
      <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Id") %>' /> 
    </ItemTemplate> 
    <EditItemTemplate> 
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>'></asp:TextBox> 
    </EditItemTemplate> 
   <FooterTemplate> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="ftrtxtunme" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Username") %>'></asp:TextBox>
   </FooterTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Do you already have any code you could provide us? This question is very vague and shows no signs of having tried anything yourself...

Comment: I have tried but unable to post the code here but i can give u sample.

Comment: <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                      <asp:Button ID="btncrtrw" runat="server" Text="AddRow" Style="color: Blue; width: 100px"
                        OnClick="btncrtrw_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>

Comment: <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>'></asp:Label>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdn" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Id") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="ftrtxtunme" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Username") %>'></asp:TextBox></FooterTemplate></Columns></asp:GridView>

Answer (score 0):

You will have to perform a sort of the whole grid on the specific rows. I'm not sure wheter the `Checked` state will make it on top or bottom but if it does not work simply change `Descending` to `Ascending`.

First select the event in which you want the sorting to be called. Let's imply it's on some button click here.

```
myButton.Click += (s, e) =>
{  
myDataGridView.Sort(dataGridViewCheckBoxColumn, ListSortDirection.Descending); 
};
```

You might want to check the [SortMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.sortmode.aspx) before sorting the grid.